# Is there any way to search for the names of text files in a directory using text input?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app in API 22, and I'm trying to use a SearchView to find txt files in a directory, is there any way to do this? Doesn't have to be anything fancy, quick and dirty is a-o.k. with me.

I've tried fiddling with what values are called in the code but it always does nothing, save for some weird messages in the logcat.

```java
    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        Intent intent;
        Boolean isFound = false;
        if (isExternalStorageReadable() && seeker.toString() != "") {
            for (int i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
                if (holder[i].getName() == seeker.getQuery().toString() + ".txt") {
                    file2 = holder[i];
                    Log.i("Hey","found it!");
                    isFound = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (isFound) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.singleDelete:
                            file2.delete();
                             holder = directory.listFiles();
                            if(holder.length == 0) {
                                intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        break;
                    case R.id.load:
                            try {
                                Log.i("Hey","it's working more!");
                                intent = new Intent(this, RollerActivity.class);
                                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file2);
                                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                                str = "";
                                List<String> objects = new ArrayList<>();
                                while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    objects.add(str);
                                }
                                intent.putExtra("name", seeker.toString());
                                intent.putExtra("hit", Integer.parseInt(objects.get(0)));
                                intent.putExtra("dmg", Integer.parseInt(objects.get(1)));
                                intent.putExtra("dice", Integer.parseInt(objects.get(2)));
                                intent.putExtra("spinner", Integer.parseInt(objects.get(3)));
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        break;

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

EDIT: I have reduced the code included to only the part I am having issues with, should make things less confusing
EDIT 2: I should also note that whenever I press the button, the message "mSecurityInputMethodService is null" pops up in the Logcat, any idea what that means? (Yes I'm using a Huawei phone)

Answer (score 0):

`File#listFiles()` returns the files in the directory, if the file in question is a directory.

From there you can parse the filenames to find whichever one you wanted.

If that's not what you mean please edit your code down to show the relevant code only. Pasting the whole class becomes tough to look at.

Comment: It is a directory, and I'll look into that soon, thank you.

Comment: Did you mean File.listFiles(), btw?

Comment: @CharlesW Yes, my mistsake.

Comment: Alright, I have reduced the amount of code in the example, should make things less confusing

Answer (score 0):

I have learned my issue was actually connected to the string comparison. I've been working with C++ and C# for too long, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if (holder[i].getName() == seeker.getQuery().toString() + ".txt")
```

to

```
if (holder[i].getName().equals ( seeker.getQuery().toString() + ".txt"))
```

In java comparing strings using `==` will check if both strings reference the same string object in memory or not.

**For example**

```
String message1 = "Hello"
String message2 = "Hello"
if (message1 == message2)
```

This will always return false because we are comparing two different objects.

Comparing strings using `String.equals()` will compare the actual contents of the string.